# launch method after child component has been rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle

I'm using a `v-if` in my parent to conditional render a child component.
Even when the child should not render the mounted function still gets executed and results in an error in console.

How does one makes sure the child component is rendered when launching a method when the child component is rendered.

In my case I'm using an autofocus:

```
mounted: function () {
        // Autofocus input on load.
        this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.input.focus());
    },
```

`Error in nextTick: "TypeError: _this.$refs.input is undefined"`

console.log(this.$refs.input) gives the object:

```
<input class="form-control" data-v-661f7e55="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<input class="form-control" ref="input" type="text" autocomplete="off">

mounted(){
      this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.input.focus())
    }
```

This is working fine for me.ref is used to register a reference to an element or a child component.

Comment: The problem is that mounted still gets executed event when the child component is in a v-if="false". And This line of code should execute after the child has been rendered on the screen.

Comment: so this mounted is in child component or in parent component?

Comment: It's in the child component.